# How do I detect non-printing input in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to detect non-printing characters in C. For example I want to detect if a user inputs <kbd>Control-B</kbd>. How do I do this in C?

Comment: I mean in Linux sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: Ctrl-B is a character. You need to define what you mean by "non-character". Lookup the `isprint()` function and update your question if you still need information.

Answer (score 2):

Put `#include <ctype.h>` in your source file. Then, where you have some variable `x` that contains a character code, the function call `isprint((unsigned char) x)` returns non-zero (true) if and only if the character is a printing character. You might prefer `isprint((unsigned char) x) || isspace((unsigned char) x)`, to include tab, new-line, and carriage return. However, it also includes formfeed and vertical tab, so you might want to test manually for certain of these characters.

The `<ctype.h>` tests are affected by the locale; they may return different results if you change the locale.

If `x` is an `int` and holds a value returned by certain of the standard library functions such as `getchar`, you can omit the cast to `unsigned char` and just use `isprint(x)`. In this case, it is also okay to pass it to these tests if the value may be `EOF` instead of a character code. (`EOF` will not be in any of the character classes; the tests will return zero for it.)

Comment: Can we assume that most systems set locale to (a version of) UTF-8, and that `isprint()` is horribly broken and unusable for most systems (reports that each individual byte of a multi-byte character is not printable by itself, leading software to assume that a printable multi-byte character is not printable)?